# Php script gives different result in browser than terminal

Tags: php, browser, terminal, centos, ldap

I have a simple php script using to test bind to MS active directory, in order to use it for login to an php application. When it runs on browser, responds error: "Can't contact LDAP server", but in terminal works fine.

OS centos 7
php 5.6.40

```
$ldad = ldap_connect('ldap://{LDAP}.{DOMAIN.COM}','389') 
    or die('Cannot connect');
ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION,3);
ldap_set_option($ldap,LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS,0);
if($bind=ldap_bind($ldap,'{USERNAME}@{DOMAIN.COM}','{PASSWORD}')) {
    echo "\n\nSuccess Binding!\n\n";
    ldap_unbind($ldap);
}
else {
    echo ldap_error($ldap);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found and has to be shared:

SElinux was enabled. I found better to run

```
semanage boolean -l
```

to find out if it was on or off, httpd_can_connect_ldap was off so I alter to on using

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_connect_ldap on
```

I hope I helped someone with familiar problem.